# Java - Запись звука с микрофона в .mp3 файл

Tags: java

Делаю программу на Java, и появилась необходимость записывать звук с микрофона длительностью, например, секунд 10, и чтобы это всё сохранялось либо в `.wav`, либо в `.mp3`, разницы большой нет. Возможно ли это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На Ваш вопрос есть [хорошая статья на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/434424/).

Я по этой статье делал реализацию записи именно в `.wav`

Вот [пример кода](https://pastebin.com/zG47QBPv):

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RecordingTest {
  // текущий звуковой файл
  private File file;
  // полное имя файла
  private String soundFileName;
  // основное имя файла
  private String filename = "samples_";
  // номер файла
  private int suffix = 0;
  // аудио формат
  private AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;
  private int MONO = 1;
  // определение формата аудио данных
  private AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(
    AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100, 16, MONO, 2, 44100, true);
  // микрофонный вход
  private TargetDataLine mike;

  // создать новый файл
  File getNewFile() {
    try {
      do {
        // новое название файла
        soundFileName = filename + (suffix++) + "." + fileType.getExtension();
        file = new File(soundFileName);
      } while (!file.createNewFile());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return file;
  }

  // запуск записи
  public void startRecording() {
    new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        // линию соединения
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
        // проверить, поддерживается ли линия
        if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Line not supported" +
            info, "Line not supported",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        try {
          // получить подходящую линию
          mike = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
          // открываем линию соединения с указанным
          // форматом и размером буфера
          mike.open(format, mike.getBufferSize());
          // поток микрофона
          AudioInputStream sound = new AudioInputStream(mike);
          // запустить линию соединения
          mike.start();
          // записать содержимое потока в файл
          AudioSystem.write(sound, fileType, file);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Line not available" +
            ex, "Line not available",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I/O Error " + ex,
            "I/O Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
      }
    }.start();
  }

  // остановка записи
  public void stopRecording() {
    mike.stop();
    mike.close();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    RecordingTest rec = new RecordingTest();
    File f = rec.getNewFile();
    rec.startRecording();
  }
}
```